# Zend Framework 2: basePath() print nothing

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am wondering why basePath() print nothing in layout.phtml. I am using zend skeleton Application. Does virtual host can make this problem?
Here is the code snippet and output.

```
echo $this->headLink(array('rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'type' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon', 'href' => $this->basePath() . '/img/favicon.ico'))
                        ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/style.css')
                        ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')
                        ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

HTML Output

```
        <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
```

How i solve this. Help will highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What should it output?

Comment: In my folder structure output should like followig: <link href="/zend/skeleton/public/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: It should not. You should set virtual host to `/zend/skeleton/public` as this is public folder (intended to be visible from outside) and then links `/css/bootstrap` will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of basePath() you should try to use [serverUrl()](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/ServerUrl.php) view helper.

Example:

```
$this->prependStylesheet($this->serverUrl('/css/style.css'))
     ->prependStylesheet($this->serverUrl('/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'))
     ->prependStylesheet($this->serverUrl('/css/bootstrap.min.css'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
    $print = $this->headLink(array('rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'type' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon', 'href' => $this->basePath() . '/img/favicon.ico'))
                                    ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/style.css')
                                    ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')
                                    ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');


>    echo $print;
```

or as a temporary solution.

```
<link href="<?php echo $this->basePath(); ?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: did anyoone here solve your problem? If not then i have updated a temporary solution for you

Comment: Eh, I'm not the questioner. What I tried to say is that there's no actual difference in what you propose and the questioners code. In both examples will the toString method be called. You are not solving the problem with just splitting his code up.

Comment: i just suggested the Zend 2 documentation way

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your controller:

```
public function baseUrl() {
    $protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http';
    $server = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $port = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 80 ? ":{$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']}" : '';
    $path = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '/\\') . '/';

    return "$protocol://$server$port$path";
}
```

If it still doesn't work, pass that as a variable to your view so that you can use it on your view.